# Derive slope in typical units from betas

Tags: regression

I used the lm() to return the betas of my linear model.  Then I used these to plot a line using curve(). What is the most simple way to calculate the slope of this line in typical slope units (ie. from 0-1)?  I could do it by making two estimates along the line and putting the x and y values into the rise/run formula, but there must be a more simple way.

example=lm(predictor~response)
curve(example)